# Can't use new redux state right after fetching a response from Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, socket.io, react-redux

I have a function "sendMessage" in React class:

```
class MessageForm extends React.Component {
...
   sendMessage = async () => {
    const { message } = this.state;


    if (message) {
      this.setState({ loading: true });

      if (this.props.isPrivateChannel === false) {
        socket.emit("createMessage", this.createMessage(), (response) => {
          this.setState({ loading: false, message: "", errors: [] });
        });
      } else {
        if (this.state.channel && this.state.channel._id === undefined) {
          socket.emit("createChannelPM", this.state.channel, async (response) => {
            const chInfo = { ...response, name: this.props.currentChannel.name };
            console.log("chInfo : ", chInfo);

            await this.props.setCurrentChannel(chInfo).then((data) => {
              if (data) {
                console.log("data : ", data);
                console.log("this.props.currentChannel : ", this.props.currentChannel);
              }
            });
          });
        }

...

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    isPrivateChannel: state.channel.isPrivateChannel,
    currentChannel: state.channel.currentChannel,
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    setCurrentChannel: async (channel) => await dispatch(setCurrentChannel(channel)),
  }
};
```

Here, in sendMessage function, I retrieve "response" from socket.io, then put this data into variable "chInfo" and assign this to Redux state, then print it right after assinging it.

And Redux Action function, "setCurrentChannel" looks like:

```
export const setCurrentChannel = channel => {
  return {
    type: SET_CURRENT_CHANNEL,
    payload: {
      currentChannel: channel
    }
  };
};
```

Reducer "SET_CURRENT_CHANNEL" looks like:

```
export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_CURRENT_CHANNEL:
            return {
                ...state,
                currentChannel: action.payload.currentChannel
            };
...
```

The backend Socket.io part look like (I use MongoDB):

```
socket.on('createChannelPM', async (data, callback) => {
            const channel = await PrivateChannel.create({
                ...data
            });
            callback(channel)
        });
```

The console.log says:

[image]

**Problem : The last output, "this.props.currentChannel" should be same as the first output "chInfo", but it is different and only print out previous value.**

However, in Redux chrome extension, "this.props.currentChannel" is exactly same as "chInfo":

[image]

How can I get and use newly changed Redux states immediately after assinging it to Redux State?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get the updated values immediately in **this.props.currentChannel**. After the redux store is updated mapStateToProps of MessageForm component is called again. Here the state **state.channel.currentChannel** will be mapped to **currentChannel**. In this component you get the updated props which will be accessed as **this.props.currentChannel**.

I believe you want to render UI with the latest data which you which you can do.